# Is the subset $K$ a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$? Prove that $\Bbb R^3 = \operatorname{span}(K)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given the subset $K = \{ (x, y, z)\in \Bbb R^3 \mid x^2 + y^2 \leq z^2\} \subset \Bbb R^3$
>
> **1)** Is $K$ a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$?
>
> **2)** Show that $\Bbb R^3 = \operatorname{span}(K)$

**1)** I suspect this is indeed a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$.

I make use of the subspace criterion to prove it.

**1.1)** Given that $(0)^2 + (0)^2 \leq (0)^2$ we indeed have $0 \in K$ so $K$ is non-empty.

**1.2)** Let $k_1 = (a, b, c), k_2 = (d, e, f) \in K$ and $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in \Bbb R$. We want to show that $\alpha_1 k_1 + \alpha_2 k_2 \in K$. If one does the calculation one finds that $\alpha_1 k_1 + \alpha_2 k_2 \in K$ holds when

$$(\alpha_1 a + \alpha_2 d)^2 + (\alpha_1 b + \alpha_2 e)^2 \leq (\alpha_1 c + \alpha_2 f)^2$$

I did not find any example breaking down the above equation. I am just wondering: is the above argument enough to justify that $K$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$? I suspect that the answer is no.

**2)** I would show that any $v \in \Bbb R^3$ can be written as a linear combination of the basis elements of $K$.

So I first need to find a basis for $K$. My issue is that I am not used to solve systems of equations with inequalities. My guess is that we better move to polar coordinates; there are two free variables $x=\lambda_1, y=\lambda_2$ and $z \geq r$. So a valid basis would be

$$ \beta = \{ (1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 1)\}$$

Given that any $v \in \Bbb R^3$ can be written as a linear combination of the basis vectors of $\beta$, it is proven that $\Bbb R^3 = span(K)$.

Do you agree? :)

Comment: 1) No it's not a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. If it would be, then $K=\mathbb R^3$ which is obviously not the case. 2) What would be a basis of $K$, or more generally, what is a basis of an unspecified set ?

Comment: To see $K$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, take $\alpha = (1, 0, 1) \in K, \beta = (0, 1, 1) \in K$, then $\alpha - \beta = (1, -1, 0) \notin K$. Your arguments in part 2) looks good to me (just cut the equation solving part).